# Some child elements are not working when I put the "ng-model" attribute in the parent element in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox

I just noticed that some of the elements disappeared once I included the ng-model attribute in my html file.

Like in my radio button. The checked radio's text turns bold using css. The "Male" button is has the checked attrib. It doesn't work when I put the "ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" attrib and run in Firefox but it works in Chrome. I just installed firefox so I assume I have the latest version.

```css
input:checked ~ span {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="radios" align="middle">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" checked><span>Male</span></label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  ng-model="ctrl.person.gender" name="gender" value="Female" id="female"><span>Female</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean on initial load? If so, instead of using the checked attribute, set your model (ie. person.gender = 'Male')

Comment: do you mean  ng-model="ctrl.person.gender = Male"? cause it's not working still.  the ng-model binds the radio buttons so when either is selected, the proper data  is received

Comment: I mean in your controller initialize: `this.person.gender = 'Male';`

Comment: anyway I have a question. In form angular validations. At what circumstances will the $invalid become true??